# Template argument dependent using/typedef declaration

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

How can I write a `using` (or `typedef`) declaration that is dependent on a template argument?
I would like to achieve something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Class
{
   // T can be an enum or an integral type
   if constexpr (std::is_enum<T>::value) {
      using Some_type = std::underlying_type_t<T>;
   } else {
      using Some_type = T;
   }
};
```

Comment: Rather do something like `std::enable_if<>`.

Comment: If all the template parameters belong to the nesting class, you can simply use `typedef`; but if the identifier itself needs to become a template, you have to define it via a `using` declaration. Just see the implementation of `std::add_const_t` in `<type_traits>`; you will learn a hell lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is exactly what `std::conditional` is for:

```
template <class T>
class Class
{
    using Some_type = typename std::conditional_t<std::is_enum<T>::value, std::underlying_type<T>, std::type_identity<T>>::type;
};
```

`std::type_identity` is from C++20, which if you don't have is easy to replicate yourself:

```
template< class T >
struct type_identity {
    using type = T;
};
```

This is required since `std::underlying_type<T>::type` does not exist if `T` is not an enum and `std::conditional` can't prevent that evaluation from occurring.